# SVG is rendered in a different way in Mozzila than Chrome

Tags: html, svg

In Google Chrome and Edge, the svg is Ok. But for Firefox in a linux it is rendered wrong.

Correct renderizartion:

[image]

How firefox shows:

[image]

I use the 'img' selector in this case, like this:

```
<img src="file.svg"/>
```

Comment: Looks like a font problem. Can you reproduce the problem with just the text and include the resulting minimal SVG in the post?

Comment: Include the font in the css styles of the svg (open the svg document in your editor)